# Can I use Google Plus sign in to authenticate my OAuth methods in app engine?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, oauth, google-plus

I successfully implemented Google Account sign in using the tutorial here for Android:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/clients/android/add_auth_code

This allows my app to successfully use endpoints in app engine while authenticated.

However now I'd like to perform some Google Plus functionality, ie: obtain some info about the user. I followed the code for the G+ signin as below:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_4_initialize_the_googleapiclient

What I'd like to know is if these 2 methods can somehow be merged? I feel like I'm asking the user to sign in twice with his Google account... Is there anyway the GoogleApiClient of G+ can be used to generate the credentials needed for the Google Endpoints authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once signed in using Google+, you're almost good to go to talk to your Backend API. Something like this was what I did:

```
   @Override
   public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    // Update the user interface to reflect that the user is signed in.
    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Signed in");
    }
    final String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName); // private GoogleAccountCredential credential;


    // call your GAE stuff


    }
```