# App-engine authenticating google account and google plus at the same time

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-plus, google-play-services

I am working on a project based on google mobile backend starter. This is set up to authenticate users using their google account - https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/mobile-backend-starter-api-reference/#secmod

I now want to get a users name and profile image as defaults for their profile. I have implemented the google plus APIs which gives me the information that I want - https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people

Unfortunately at the moment I am asking the user to log in to the application with their google account and then asking them to log in again to get their google plus information. So my question is this: is there a way to modify the google plus login such that it takes the authentication from mobile backend starter rather than requiring a separate login?

This is a similar question [Can I use Google Plus sign in to authenticate my OAuth methods in app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25656511/can-i-use-google-plus-sign-in-to-authenticate-my-oauth-methods-in-app-engine) but I specifically want my standard sign in to authenticate the google plus (rather than the other way around) as very few people have an android phone without a google account but a larger percentage dont have a google plus account

Answer (score 0):

If in your application you provide a "Sign-in with Google" functionality then you can upgrade that functionality with "Google SignIn Plus". Please refer to the document [1].Also go through the document[2], it gives you an idea how to use the Google+Sign In with your android application.

[1]**Google SignIn Plus:** https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#update-to-plus

[2]**Google SignInfor Android:** https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in